# Flutter Firebase Analytics Active User Realtime Count Not Showing?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

After upgrading Flutter SDK to 2.8.1 and Firebase Plugins. Realtime active users count showing zero always in `Firebase console Dashboard -> Users in last 30 minutes`.

We have more than 5k app users before upgrading SDK it was working fine showing 2k plus users last 30 minutes, but after upgrading the flutter SDK and plugins it came down to zero. Help me out to fix this issue. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Flutter Plugin,

```
firebase_analytics: ^9.1.0
firebase_core: ^1.10.0
```

Android Dependencies,

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:20.1.0'
```

Flutter Doctor,

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-arm, locale
    en-IN)
    • Flutter version 2.8.1 at
      /Users/maclap/Documents/developer/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 77d935af4d (9 weeks ago), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
    • Engine revision 890a5fca2e
    • Dart version 2.15.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/maclap/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Nokia 4 2 (mobile) • DT89571GA1962616726 • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
    • Chrome (web)       • chrome              • web-javascript • Google Chrome 98.0.4758.102

• No issues found!
```

Comment: same issue here